# Running NPM install fails

Tags: laravel, npm, homestead

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/code/node_modules/@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss/node_modules/commander/package.json.630663003
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/node_modules/@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss/node_modules/commander/package.json.630663003'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I keep getting this error when I run npm install.

I have deleted node_modules folder, packages.json-lock and cleared the npm cache

I am using Homestead.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve this issue.

I do know it is an issue with Laravel Homestead though, as Laragon did not have the issue. I have decided to use Laragon for now.